# Where can I ask about hardware development?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, scope

I have a question about the viability, and requirements of "upgrading" a Micro-USB port to a UBS-C port, purely for the purpose of charging, though I don't know which Stack to ask on.

My question is about:

- The requirements of Micro-USB vs USB-C connectivity in terms of hardware (i.e. to the board)
- The viability of this "upgrade"

I do have photos I can provide, as well as the reasoning for the replacement/change (charging connectivity issues).

I've seen some similar questions about this kind of thing, which suggest Super User, but I don't know if my question fits the site.

Comment: If you're specifically interested in SU, a better place to ask for topicality would be their meta; they're the experts on their scope

Comment: @bobble my only reason for mentioning SU was just because a couple of others had asked similar (but different) questions, which gave the suggestion of asking on SU, but I'll ask over there anyway, just in case :)

Comment: [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be the right place

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest asking this on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com), unless it is about modifying a specific device for which we already have a more focused Q&A site, like [Android](https://android.stackexchange.com) or [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com).

This is not likely to be a Super User question, unless your question merely focuses on the software aspects of getting the device to charge (e.g., driver installation) after doing such a hardware modification.